# Postfix local transport to guerrilla SMTP daemon: mail for 127.0.0.1 loops back to myself

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am trying to send the bounced email from postfix to guerrilla on the same server. My hostname is nsprompt.com and my transport map looks like this

bounce@nsprompt.com smtp:[127.0.0.1]

I have postfix running in port 587 & guerrilla running in port 25.

Each time when postfix tries to send emails to bounce@nsprompt.com the following happens

```
Oct  6 21:52:57 nsprompt postfix/smtp[663239]: 2F0C417B58D: to=<bounce@nsprompt.com>, relay=none, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for 127.0.0.1 loops back to myself)
Oct  6 21:52:57 nsprompt postfix/qmgr[662808]: 2F0C417B58D: remove
```

How to send mail from postfix to guerrilla under the same server successfully?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is guerrilla?

Comment: I am using this open-source https://github.com/flashmob/go-guerrilla. A lightweight SMTP server written in Go made for receiving large volumes of mail.
postfix & guerrilla use the same hostname.